# XML Document created with SAX SVG Parser doesn't find attribute with getAttribute()

Tags: svg, xml-parsing, java-11, sax

I want to remove an image tag from a SVG file in case the image has a base64 encoded image.

```
String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
SAXSVGDocumentFactory fac = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);

Document svgDoc = fac.createDocument(inFile.toURI().toString());
```

To delete the image tag I do this:

```
public static final Pattern BASE64_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^.*data:image/(?:png|jpg|jpeg);base64,.*");

private static void deleteBase64Images(Document doc) {
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");

    int length = nodes.getLength();
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Element image = (Element)nodes.item(i);
        String attribute = image.getAttribute("xlink:href");
        if (BASE64_PATTERN.matcher(attribute).matches()) {
            image.getParentNode().removeChild(image);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a minimal SVG that has an image with an attribute "xlink:href":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" width="51.1939in"
height="23.6013in"
viewBox="0 0 3685.96 1699.29" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
class="st38">   

<image x="0" y="50" width="64" height="64" image-rendering="optimizeSpeed"
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAA9SURBVChTfY8xDgAgCMT4/3cZbzhzRI0o2IVAu2AAWKG7u9PmnlhS8wlOKVJwS6GDSooIOinii04K+0kAHIw2/SFJpU9IAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">        
</image>
</svg>
```

However, the line `image.getAttribute("xlink:href");` returns an empty String. What is strange is that `image.getAttributes().item(i)` returns an attribute with the name "xlink:href" (for some i).

Consider this code that uses `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` instead:

```
private static String preprocessSVG(File originalFile) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(originalFile);
        deleteBase64Images(document);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this case, the line `image.getAttribute("xlink:href");` returns the correct attribute. Why is the Document parsed by `org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory` behaving so strange?
What am I missing here?

The Document Implementation is `SVGOMDocument`.

Comment: The regEx doesn't match the code for the image. The dot matches any single character, except a line break. In your code you have 2 line breaks

Comment: @enxaneta The value of "xlink:href" doesn't have a line breaks. "attribute" should only hold the string "data:image/...QmCC". Even if there were line breaks in it, attribute should not be empty.

Comment: you'd need to call getAttributeNS to get an attribute from the xlink namespace.

Comment: @RobertLongson you mean `image.getAttributeNS("xlink", "href");`? Returns an empty string, too.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the hint. This means that this question is a duplicate of another question. The provided answer works for me.